# Why is my awk print not showing up on the terminal

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following script which does a "which -a" on a command then a "ls -l" to let me know if it's a link or not .. ie "grep" since I have gnu commands installed (Mac with iTerm).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
which -a $1 | xargs -I{} ls -l "{}" \
| awk '{for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) $i = ""; sub(/^ */, ""); print}'
```

When I run this from the script "test grep" I receive no output, but when I run it via "bash -x test grep" I receive the following:

```
bash -x test grep
+ which -a grep
+ xargs '-I{}' ls -l '{}'
+ awk '{for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) $i = ""; sub(/^ */, ""); print}'
/usr/local/bin/grep -> ../Cellar/grep/3.1/bin/grep
/usr/bin/grep
```

The last 2 lines is what I'm looking to display.  Thought this would be easier to do ;-) .. I also tried appending the pipe thinking printf would fix the issue:

```
| while read path
do
   printf "%s\n" "$path"
done
```

Thanks and .. Is there a better way to get what I need?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you mean `type grep`?

Comment: Yes, please specify what output you want? Are you trying to print the actual locations and not the sym links, e.g., `/usr/bin/grep` and `../Cellar/grep/3.1./bin/grep` ?

Comment: As an aside, there are **really** better ways to do all of this. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [How can I get a file's permissions or other metadata without parsing `ls` output?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087). And `which` isn't part of the shell and doesn't have access to its internal state, so it isn't always accurate about where the shell would actually get a command from; `type` is a better alternative if only targeting bash, or `command -v` for all POSIX shells.

Comment: ...btw, what's your platform? Do you have GNU `readlink`?

Comment: Yes, Platform is Mac with gnu coreutils+ installed, I'll look into "type" and I do have "readlink"

Comment: Looks like "type" and "readlink" is the better way.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you named your script `test`.

If you want to run a command that's not in your `PATH`, you need to specify the directory it's in, e.g. `./test`.

You're not getting an error for trying to run `test` because there is a built-in bash command called `test` that is used instead. For extra confusion, the standard `test` produces no output.

In conclusion:

- Use `./` to run scripts in the current directory.
- Never call your test programs `test`.

Comment: I find that I do a lot of finding a path to a command than running it through a "ls -l" to get a better understanding on which command I'm really running.  Thought I would script it.  The last 2 lines of the bash -x is what I'm looking to display.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the never naming a script "test" .. old habits are hard to break (I came from a non-unix background.

I ended with the following

```
for i in $(which -a $1)
do
   stat $i | awk NR==1{'$1 = ""; sub(/^ */, ""); print}'
done
```

or simpler

```
for i in $(which -a $1)
do
  stat -c %N "$i"
done
```

Comment: awk syntax is `awk 'script'`, not `awk some-of-script'rest-of-script'`. Fix your script `awk NR==1{'$1 = ""; sub(/^ */, ""); print}'` to have the `'` delimiters **around** the script (`awk 'NR==1{$1 = ""; sub(/^ */, ""); print}'`), rather than starting half way through the script. Not saying that loop is a good approach in general of course.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following shell function:

```
cmdsrc() {
  local cmd_file cmd_file_realpath
  case $(type -t -- "$1") in
    file) cmd_file=$(type -P -- "$1")
          if [[ -L "$cmd_file" ]]; then
            echo "$cmd_file is a symlink" >&2
          elif [[ -f "$cmd_file" ]]; then
            echo "$cmd_file is a regular file" >&2
          else
            echo "$cmd_file is not a symlink or a regular file" >&2
          fi
          cmd_file_realpath=$(readlink -- "$cmd_file") || return
          if [[ $cmd_file_realpath != "$cmd_file" ]]; then
            echo "...the real location of the executable is $cmd_file_realpath" >&2
          fi
          ;;
    *)    echo "$1 is not a file at all: $(type -- "$1")" >&2 ;;
  esac
}
```

...used as such:

```
$ cmdsrc apt
/usr/bin/apt is a symlink
...the real location of the executable is /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/apt
$ cmdsrc ls
/bin/ls is a regular file
$ cmdsrc alias
alias is not a file at all: alias is a shell builtin
```

Comment: The intent is not just bells-and-whistles, but also to showcase good practices -- `[[ ]]` for comparisons, `type` instead of `which`, failure handling with `|| return`, correct quoting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Took some suggestions and came up with the following:
The prt-underline is just a fancy printf function.  I decided not to go with readline since the ultimate command resolution may be unfamiliar to me and I only deal with regular files .. so does't handle every situation but in the end gives me the output I was looking for.  Thanks for all the help.

```
llt ()
{
    case $(type -t -- "$1") in
        function)
            prt-underline "Function";
            declare -f "$1"
        ;;
        alias)
            prt-underline "Alias";
            alias "$1" | awk '{sub(/^alias /, ""); print}'
        ;;
        keyword)
            prt-underline "Reserved Keyword"
        ;;
        builtin)
            prt-underline "Builtin Command"
        ;;
        *)

        ;;
    esac;
    which "$1" &> /dev/null;
    if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
        prt-underline "File";
        for i in $(which -a $1);
        do
            stat "$i" | awk 'NR==1{sub(/^  File: /, ""); print}';
        done;
    fi
}
```